# how to add text link inside a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I want to place some text as link inside a div.

For example, I want to place text 'Google' with hyperlink `<a href="http://www.google.com"` inside a div having class-id as "my-link".

How can this be done using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Class and ID is not the same.

If ID try this:

```
$('#my-link').html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

Demo [**with ID**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/)

If Class try this:

```
$('.my-link').html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
   ^
```

Demo [**with class**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/1/)

Comment: thanks @Sergio for your solution, can you please make a js-fiddle to showcase it. Sorry for my novice skills :P, but don't know how excatly to place this inside my html document.

Comment: @user2773294, just added demos to my answer.

Comment: thanks again @Sergio, I actually needed this within appropriate script tag with necessary jquery-lib path associated with this. Which I can simply take from here and place in my document head tag.

I checked js-fiddle but it appears in same manner as it appears here, placing this inside my html document doesn't make it work.

Comment: @user2773294, you could do this with plain javascript, no jQuery. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/2/

Comment: with your new-js fiddle I added the javascript code in my documents head section as given below..

`<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('my-link').innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
</script>`

but it didn't work. Also I am using class-name instead id as selector for div (although I changed my class-name as id in html while tried your solution.).

Comment: @user2773294, the code will not work in the head selection just as it is, it has to be added after the html. Or around a function like `window.onload = function(){ //code here };`

Comment: @user2773294, if you have jQuery you can paste this one free in the head: http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/3/

Comment: @user2773294, for plain javascript with class use this in the head or anywhere else: http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/4/

Comment: Got your point, either code needs to place at the botoom of document before closing body tag, or with window.onload function in the head...its working both way now.

but as I said 'my-div' is a class name in my case, and you example consists on id name. Can you please make this accordingly. I tried changing `document.getElementsByClass('my-link')...` but it didn't worked.

Also I have some existing content with-in 'my-div' (sorry forgot to mention before), I want to add this link text further in that. hope it will not replace the existing content and place this new link-text.

Comment: @user2773294 my last comment was with class and plain javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/4/

Comment: Able to do this now with your last fiddle, but its replaced the existing content of my div and place this link text. How can I add this link-text to the next of my existing content.

Comment: @user2773294, aha, didn't know it was not empty. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/5/

Comment: Thanks @Sergio, its worked as desired. However got a next issue further. The link-text I, originally, needed to place in multiple li elements (having same class name) but its appearing within the first li element only and not in rest.

Here is the actual website `http://www.timelessluxwatches.com/timeless_new/armin/`.

The link-text is currently appearing inside the first watch-box (bootom of page) below price tag '$ 20000.00' (you would need to move mouse there to see the text as its appearing in white color as website still under construction). This link-text had to be in every watch-box.

Comment: @user2773294, I see you have jQuery. Can it be a jQuery solution?

Comment: @user2773294, with plain javascript for many elements with same class http://jsfiddle.net/3sUvg/7/

Comment: Great and many thanks, to solve this. Its just worked like a miracle. The last thing, the link-url is not be a typical url like "http://www..." (curse to my developer for last min update) instead it is something like `data-reveal-id="text-5"`.

When putting this inside `a href = ""` the javascript not taking this and removing this leaving <a> tag like plain text. Is there any way through variable to make it pass through <a> tag.

Comment: As my reputation does not allow me to accept this as answer and vote it up. Please consider this as solution for my question, vote it up and final answer. Many Thanks @Sergio.

Comment: @user2773294, sorry, was having dinner. You can always accept an answer. Reputation is only for voting.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
$('.my-link').html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
```

but it would add hyperlink to all **.my-link** divs, so it's better to add an **ID** to div and use the **ID** on **jQuery** code.

Answer (score 2):

If `my-link` is the class of the target div then

```
$('.my-link').html(function(idx, html){
    return html.replace(/Google/g, '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KsRKg/)